# Stripe payments from ajax content on mobile returning error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to send stripe payments from a form that is loaded via ajax. The payment window opens perfectly, but when you click to pay it says the original window has closed. So next time before clicking pay I go back and look, and the ajax content that had loaded has vanished.

Would anyone have any idea how I can stop the ajax loaded content from closing before the payment is processed?

Here's the code i'm using:

```
      var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
    key: 'pk_test_*********',
    token: function(response) {     $("form").append(valueInput).append(emailInput).submit();
    }
  });

$(document).on('mousedown', '#payment-submit', function(e) {
    // Open Checkout with further options
    handler.open({
      name: 'Project P',
      email: '<?=$_SESSION['Email'];?>',
      description: ValueDescription,
      currency: 'GBP',
      amount: ValueAmount
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Please note the payment is working fine on desktop chrome as a popup opens, but on mobile it opens in a new tab and the ajax loaded form is removed from the parent in the previous page.